# CodeMirror: TextMarker vs Mode

Tags: codemirror, codemirror-modes

I'm experimenting with text annotation in CodeMirror.

What's the difference between using `TextMarker` and `Mode`?

It seems that both would be the job done, but the `Mode` API seems more complicated.

Are there significant performance improvements with `Mode`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, highlighting by a mode is computed on demand, whereas making all text in a document to have the right color requires you to do it yourself, and update it yourself whenever the document changes. For big documents, this is going to be very expensive.